# having trouble unzipping with php / ssh2_connect

Tags: php, ssh2-exec

I'm trying to implement php in combination with ssh2_connect in order to unzip on a remote folder by using this script:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($ipaddress, 22);

    if (!$connection) {
        throw new Exception("Could not connect to server.");
    }

    if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) {
        throw new Exception("Authentication failed!");
    }
    else {
        $unzip = "unzip $filename";
        //$unzip = "unzip $filename -d /home/upload/homes/folder/";
        if ( ($stream = ssh2_exec( $connection, $unzip ) ) ){
            $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
            ssh2_sftp_unlink($sftp, $filename);
        }
    }
```

my zip-file contains multiple files but the unzip function returns just 1 file with 0kB.
When i login with ssh i can successfully unzip the file.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

libssh2 behaves strangely. you might have better luck with phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec("unzip $filename")
?>
```

If that doesn't work you can get the phpseclib logs and post them for further diagnosis.